# Euler class is odd under orientation, thus its integral over a manifold will be even.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

I learned a statement from others:

> "Euler class is odd under orientation, thus its integral over a manifold $M$ is even."

I cannot fully appreciate it, can someone show this explicitly?

The even/odd here I suppose it means the orientation.

Answer (score 1):

This just means that the Euler characteristic of the manifold is independent of the orientation:
$$\chi(-M)=\chi(M)$$

Comment: Yeah! More explicitly: $$\chi(M)=\int_M e_M=-\int_{-M}e_M=-\int_{-M}-e_{-M}=\chi(-M)$$